# Is my understanding of *mapping* correct?

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell. When I'm reading books (the russian translate of them) I often see the *mapping* word... I'm not sure I understand it right.

In my understanding: the *mapping* - this is the getting of *new value* on the base of some *old value*. So it is a result of *any* function with parameters (at least one), or data constructor. The new value isn't obliged to have the same type, as old.

I.e.

```
-- mapping samples:
func a b = a + b 
func' a = show a
func'' a = a
func''' a = Just a
```

Am I right?

Comment: Mapping in general refers to getting some value based on its linkage to some other value, not really old and new values. Can you share some background on where you saw 'mapping' in the book?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I often see this word in the russian translate of this ( http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters )  book. At first I thought that it means only the `map` function using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you have understood is correct. Mapping means getting new values based on the old value by applying it to some function. The new value may or may not be of the same type (of the old value). In mathematics, the word mapping and function is actually used interchangeably.

There is another concept related to mapping: `map`

map is a famous higher order function which can perform mapping on a list of values.

```
λ> map (+ 1) [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

In the previous example, you are using the `map` function to apply the function `(+ 1)` on each of the list values.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know about the `map` function existing.

Comment: In addition (since this is tagged [tag:haskell]), you can differentiate between contextless mapping (like `map`, function application) and `fmap` - which does the mapping after the extraction from monadic/applicative/whatever context. And indeed for lists `fmap = map`